# Heap Corruption Detected C

Tags: c

I've been dangling with C and a bit of cryptography, anyways I try to dynamically allocate a string to input a plain text and a key which i use to get a cypher text. Program works until I decide to free the allocated memory. then produces an error stating: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#73) at this and this address; checked all the other posts, nothing, I'm confused, pls help. Here's the code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int plainSize = 0;
   int keySize = 0;

   InputInteger(keySize,"key size");
   InputInteger(plainSize,"plaintext size");

   char *plaintext = (char*)malloc((plainSize + 1) * sizeof(char));
   char *key = (char*)malloc((keySize + 1) * sizeof(char));
   char *cypher =  (char*)malloc((plainSize + 1) * sizeof(char));

   InputString(plaintext, "plaintext");
   InputString(key, "key");


   cypher=ViginereEncrypt(plaintext, key);
   printf("\n%s encypted with Viginere key %s is %s", plaintext, key, cypher);
   printf("\n\n");

   free(plaintext);
   free(key);
   free(cypher);
}

char *ViginereEncrypt(char *plaintext,char *key)
{
   int i = 0;
   char *cypherText = (char*)malloc((strlen(plaintext) + 1)*sizeof(char));
   printf("\n%d\n", strlen(plaintext) + 1);
   for (i = 0;i < strlen(plaintext);i++)
    *cypherText++ =(*plaintext++ - 'A' + *key++ - 'A' -1) % ('Z' - 'A') +    'A';
   cypherText[i] = '\0';
   return cypherText;
}
void InputInteger(int myInteger,char name [100])
{
   printf("Input a number for %s : ",name);
   scanf("%d", &myInteger);
}
void InputString(char myString[],char name[100])
{
   printf("Input a string for %s  : ",name);
   scanf("%s", myString);
}
```

Is the problem with the allocation inside the function? Think it shouldn't be since I "copied" the cypher to the function return and then freed it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: With respect to @Weather Wane's good answer and pointing at security issues, there are few more issues on memory management in your program, that haven't been covered. Please compile this program with correction suggestions, turn all warnings on and have a good learning time debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call `InputInteger(keySize,"key size");` cannot put a value to `keySize`. Both `keySize` and `plainSize` will remain as `0`. So you are allocating 1 byte of memory for each string, only enough for a terminator. Computer melts.

I suggest these changes, firstly to pass back the input value

```
void InputInteger(int *myInteger, char name [100])     // add the *
{
   printf("Input a number for %s : ", name);
   scanf("%d", myInteger);                             // remove the &
}
```

then change the way you call it.

```
InputInteger(&keySize, "key size");                    // add the &
InputInteger(&plainSize, "plaintext size");            // add the &
```

so that you pass the address of the variable you wish to alter.

**Edit:** That is not to say there are no other vulnerabilites in the code. The string length may be a negative number, you should be doing some input validation. Also the `InputString` function is open to malicious attack or accidental fault, where the user can say the string length is 2 and then wreck the stack, with some curious larger input which takes over the machine because it is executable code which the perp has placed there to steal your beans.